# Loading and unloading mechanism for items of a listbox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, listbox

I want to create an application in WPF using C# in which I want to introduce Loading and unloading mechanism on items of a listbox in a certain visible area. In brief, there are a ton of items present in Listbox, while the user scrolling down or up inside a visible region then the visible items will be only take the memory or will be loaded and rest of the items whose are not visible they will not take any memory or will be unloaded.

I don't have any basic idea about how to go for it.Could anyone please let me know how to go for it, and what should be the basic steps I have to take and which articles should I have to look? Any clue would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If u ask me, I think your method is good, not not feasible on a listbox. A listbox allows scrolling, so you have to take account the UI of the listbox. Example like, when u scroll down all the way, then because of your unloading of unseen data, and u load only the visible part, what happens to the scrollbar? Theoretically, it move back to the top most. As a user, will you find it irritating? But if you put this in a grid view, and perhaps introduce pagination, it would be much much more easier.

Comment: What I am thinking is, instead of setting my scroll bar to the top most i will leave the scroll bar as it is and according the ScrollViewer ViewPort region I'll decide the the Visible region and will load and unload items accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

you may look at [VirtualMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode.aspx) this is one of the approaches to control the loading of items.

Comment: Can you please share any sample application if you have.

Comment: @SharpUrBrain there is already code sample in the link I provided. if you want to have working sample here is a codeproject's one: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/VirtualModeListView.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The comment above seems valid - if you try to do this as the user scrolls then it's going to create a very unstable UI.  What about just adding a "more..." option at the bottom of the list if there's more data?